# TFS 2017 on Prem asking for credentails constantly

Tags: tfs, tfs-2017

We have an issue when some team members are using TFS from home over VPN into our corporate network. If they are using their personal computer instead of the corporate computer. When they first come to the TFS endpoint they are prompted with entering their Domain username/password. They enter it in then they are able to continue to TFS properly. the issue lies after that. if they sit idle for 20 min or so TFS removes their session and they need to re-login again. if they had a Work item or storyboard open they need to find it again and continue where they left off. Is this a configuration value in TFS? is there any solution to extend this time?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to go to `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager` to store the TFS username and password in `Windows Credential`, to see whether it helps you.